# TypeError: deckcards() missing 1 required positional argument: 'trumps'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a top trump game and want to get a local variable used in a different function. This is all the necessary code. hello() is the menu but is not relevant here.

```
def deckcards():
  cards = trumps.cards // 2
  print(cards)

def trumps():
  cards = int(input("""How many cards would you like?
  (Even number from 4, 30): """))
  if cards % 2 == 0 and cards != 0:
    if cards < 4 or cards > 30:
      print("Please enter an even number from 4 to 30")
      hello()

    else:
      deckcards()

  else:
    print("Invalid amount.")
    hello()
```

Comment: your code is incomplete. we do not see what `trumps` is. we do not see what `trump.cards` is. why arent you returning `return trumps.cards // 2` from `deckcards()`. Read about [scoping rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules). avoid globals, pass whats needed as function parameters.

Comment: Make sure you show the errors and tracebacks as text in the body of the question. Don't hide errors in the title.

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass the variable as a function parameter to the second function. You may want to read this https://www.pythoncentral.io/fun-with-python-function-parameters/

For example:

```
def deck_cards(num_cards):
  cards = num_cards // 2
  print(cards)
```

num_cards is the parameter passed by calling deck_cards(52)